# Force vim-preview to use Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, vim

I use `vim-preview` plugin for previewing markup files. But it opens Firefox every time (even if Chrome is default browser in my system). How can I prevent it and force vim-preview to run Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is in `:help PreviewBrowsers`.

It looks like you can just put this in .vimrc:

```
let g:PreviewBrowsers='google-chrome'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is My `.vimrc` at Ubuntu12.04:

```
""" WebBrowser Preview  
nnoremap <C-w>f :silent update<Bar>silent !firefox %:p &<CR>  
nnoremap <C-w>c :silent update<Bar>silent !chromium-browser %:p &<CR>  
" nnoremap <C-w>i :silent update<Bar>silent !iexplorer %:p &<CR>  
" nnoremap <C-w>o :silent update<Bar>silent !opera %:p &<CR>  
" nnoremap <C-w>s :silent update<Bar>silent !safari %:p &<CR>
```

- Reference
  Preview current HTML file: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file