# Sublime Text 2 -> Vim, How do I open html file in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, vim, render

Just getting started with Vim and am writing a basic HTML file.  In SublimeText you could just right click and open in browser, but i'm having trouble finding how to do the same with Vim.  I have Ubuntu and I want to preview the code in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425232/force-vim-preview-to-use-google-chrome?rq=1 maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:!` to execute external commands within vim (see `:help :!`). The `%` sign in an `:ex` command expands to the current file name (see `:help :_%`). That being said, you can use the following to first save the file and then open it in the browser of your choice

```
:w|!google-chrome %
```

If you'd rather use firefox or chromium, use `firefox` or `chromium`, respectively, in place of `google-chrome`. If you're on mac or linux you could also use the `open` or `xdg-open` commands, respectively, to open the file in its default application. Don't want to type that out every time? Make your own command or mapping in your .vimrc.

```
command! ViewInBrowser :w|!google-chrome %
nnoremap <leader>b :ViewInBrowser<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks Conner! How do I open my .vimrc??

Comment: If it already exists you can use `:e $MYVIMRC`. Otherwise, create one with `:e $HOME/.vimrc` (using GNU/Linux or Mac) or `:e $HOME/_vimrc` (using Windows).